How to resend an event to an HTTP integration in ChirpStack?
I have setup a private LoraWAN network with little hurdles along the way but so far I managed to get everything working very smoothly.
I am using ChirpStack as a Network Server and just a request logger as an Application server.
In ChirpStack I have added an HTTP integration in order to be able to receive events in my Application server - this works as expected. The problem arises whenever the Application is down for whatever reason, any events that have occurred during the downtime appear to be lost, since ChirpStack does not appear to retry forwarding the events to the Application server.
Is it possible to configure ChirpStack so that it will try to resend events if it does not receive a code 200 response from the Application server?
I tried going through the integration settings in the administration UI but they are quite limited. I expect that maybe it would be a setting in a configuration file somewhere or something similar?
